# How to do this diagonal matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

can you help me with this type of diagonal matrix?

```
  |      1| 
  |     1 |
  |    1  |
I=|   1   |
  |  1    |
  | 1     |
  |1      |
```

I don't know how to do it in Matlab.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
fliplr(eye(7))
```

This results in

```
ans =

     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 4):

some more options (for the sake of completeness):

```
rot90(eye(7))

flipud(eye(7))
```